# Windows Batch Static List Rename-Move

Tags: arrays, windows, file, batch-file, for-loop

I relatively new to `Batch Scripts` and i am trying to create a windows batch file that renames a static array values in one group against an static array values in another - moving to another folder. Something like this:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set currentDate=%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%
set fromPath=C:\
set toPath=C:\Temp\    

set fileList=(temp1.txt temp2.txt temp3.txt)
set toList=(name1 name2 name3)
```

I'm looking at this style of array as its looks easier for the user i'm giving it to to add to the list.

Alone (without the toList) the fileList works fine:

```
for %%i in %fileList% do (
    IF EXIST %FromPath%%%i 
      ren %FromPath%%%i %%~ni_%currentDate%%%~xi & 
      move %FromPath%%%~ni_%currentDate%%%~xi %toPath%
)
```

But obviously this does not do the renaming from `toList` in the same order as the list in `toList`.

I tried code with a counter with an index like this (tried other variants of below aswell) with no luck:

```
for /L %%i IN (0,1,10) DO (
  IF EXIST %FromPath%%fileList[%%i]%
    ren %FromPath%%%i %%~ni_%currentDate%%%~xi & 
    move %FromPath%%%~ni_%currentDate%%%~xi %toPath%
)
```

Is something like this possible? If not, I'm open to any other suggestion to the above.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set currentDate=%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%
set FromPath=C:\
set toPath=C:\Temp\    

set fileList=(temp1.txt temp2.txt temp3.txt)
set toList=(name1 name2 name3)

rem Separate toList elements into an array
set i=0
for %%a in %toList% do (
   set /A i+=1
   set "toList[!i!]=%%a"
)

set i=0
for %%f in %fileList% do (
   set /A i+=1
   IF EXIST %FromPath%%%f (
      ren %FromPath%%%f %%~Nf_%currentDate%%%~Xf
      for %%i in (!i!) do move %FromPath%%%~Nf_%currentDate%%%~Xf %toPath%!toList[%%i]!
   )
)
```

For further information about array management in Batch files, see: [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Comment: 'move C:\test1_20152108.txt C:\Temp\    !toList[1]!
The syntax of the command is incorrect.'

'move C:\test2_20152108.txt C:\Temp\    !toList[2]!
The syntax of the command is incorrect.'

The output with echo is something like this... C:\>(
set /A i+=1
 IF EXIST C:\test1.txt (
ren C:\test1.txt test1_20152108.txt
 for %i in (!i!) do move C:\test1_20152108.txt C:\Temp\    !toList[%i]!
)
)

Comment: You have wrong additional spaces in `set toPath=C:\Temp\    ` line in your original code. Is better to enclose the values in quotes this way: `set "FromPath=C:\"` - `set "toPath=C:\Temp\"` - etc...

Comment: @tranceport: Did my solution worked after complete the modifications suggested?

Comment: no the toList[%%i] did not convert to the value in the array, even with the " " in the set lines